# regex to extract a value from a string

Tags: c#, regex

```
 t=1814994788352,slot=35, cycle=6, nullFrameFlag=0, ppFlag=0, spyFlag=0
```

I have this line, and using regex i would like to extract the cycle value.

I am trying this but it doesn't work.

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line, @"cycle=\d,");
if (match.Success)
{
    string key = match.Value;
}
```

Comment: @aelor, you might have to explain jamun :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@"(?<=cycle=)\d+"
```

use this regex. HTH

for further reference , better search for similar questions and learn regex, its helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried capturing the value in a group:

```
Regex.Match(line, @"cycle=(?<cycle>\d),").Groups["cycle"].Value
```

Not tested the code, but something along those lines should work.